# Optimize a regex validating a version string

Tags: .net, regex

I develop an application which installs updates. These updates have a version id (this version id is created as a part of the application and the format is a fixed requirement) and I use a regex to parse/validate their id. Each group must be separated by a dot. The id must have 2 digits in the first group, one or two digits in the second group and the third group and at least one digit in the last group.

The regex I use is the following:

```
^[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,}$
```

[image: regex in use]

The regex works like expected but when I look at it I have a feeling telling me that I can make it better, smarter and and and and ...

Should I stay with this solution or how would you make it better?

The regex should work with the .NET-Framework Regex class.

Comment: What kind of version number are you parsing? is this some kind of version number you have created? Or are you trying to parse something like [semver](http://semver.org/)? Its going to be difficult to answer without knowing the requirements. Also, could you please include your regex in the question instead of embedded in an image? Thanks.

Comment: I've edited my post

Answer (score 1):

Since the second and third segment are similar, you can put them in a non-capturing group with quantifier.

If you allow/want the first digit to be \$ 0 \$ in your first group, the expression is ok as it is. Otherwise, you can restrict the first digit to be `[1-9]`.

You can have `+` quantifier instead of `{1,}` as they are essentially the same :)

```
^[0-9]{2}(?:\.[0-9]{1,2}){2}\.[0-9]+$
```

and for unpadded version matches:

```
^[1-9][0-9](?:\.[0-9]{1,2}){2}\.[0-9]+$
```